# 12 seconds to Copy/paste 6 simple cells. How to speed up the code?

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have a very simple code that takes almost 12 seconds to execute. It used to take under a second but about 2/3 months ago all the simple copy/paste macros takes several seconds.
Not sure if it has to do with the MS versions or another software that are interfering with clipboard.

Other common errors that started occurring around the same time was:

1. Excel could not copy the content to the clipboard it is in use by another application
2. Not Enough Memory
3. This picture is too large and will be truncated

This code takes about 12 seconds to execute:

```
Sub RunTime_Seconds()


Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
StartTime = Timer

lzCalc = Application.Calculation

With Application
 .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 .ScreenUpdating = False
 .DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").copy
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ActiveSheet.Range("A2").copy
ActiveSheet.Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ActiveSheet.Range("A3").copy
ActiveSheet.Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ActiveSheet.Range("A4").copy
ActiveSheet.Range("B4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ActiveSheet.Range("A5").copy
ActiveSheet.Range("B5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ActiveSheet.Range("A6").copy
ActiveSheet.Range("B6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

 .Calculation = lCalc
 .ScreenUpdating = True
 .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

  SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

  MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Please Help

I have researched online but unable to find users with similar problems. Usually the "slow" process are due to complicated codes.

Comment: You have `lzCalc` vs `lCalc`: do something about it. The copy code can be reduced to `ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B6").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A6").Value`. Without you sharing more information about what's going on in your workbook, it's impossible to help.

Comment: Is it a shared workbook?

Comment: The IzCal is just to see how long it actually took to execute the code, its normally not a part of the code. Also it does not have a significant impact on the execution time.

Comment: I would like to share more about the workbook but what you see its all there is to it. Its a brand new workbook that contain just this code and no more. This how it looks the sheet looks from A1:A6: 
1
2
3
4
5
6
.I made this WB just to troubleshoot and try to find the reason why it takes almost 12 seconds to execute the code. All i am doing is copying to A1:A6 to B1:B6 one cell at the time.  When i use the code mention above (=) it executes within milliseconds, unfortunately i am unable to replace the standard copy/paste code for all other workbooks used.

Comment: I think VBasic's comment about `lzCalc` is that you refer to it as `lzCalc` once, but then `lCalc` when you write the value back - note the missing `z`.

Comment: If you replace **each** copy/paste with a singular `ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value` etc.. and it doesn't run as slowly - perhaps there is an issue with your Windows copy/paste buffer? Does copy/pasting manually run slowly, in Excel, or elsewhere?

Comment: That is my thoughts as well. Manually copy/paste is fine, no delays. What I also find strange is when I hold F8 down and do one line at the time the code executes within 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have add-ins enabled that might have negative impact on performance of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but there are no add-ins activated.